# join 3 таблиц с фильтрацией

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select, join

У меня есть 3 таблицы.

**Таблица 1 - Страна:**

| PK id_страны | Название страны |

**Таблица 2 - Город**

| PK id_города | FK id_страны | название города |

**Таблица 3 - Дом**

| PK id_дома | FK город | название дома |

Нужно чтобы отображались страны в которых во всех городах нет домов.

Я сумел написать такой запрос:

```
SELECT country.Name FROM Country AS country
INNER JOIN City AS city ON country.CountryID = city.CountryID
LEFT JOIN Building AS building ON city.CityID = building.CityID 
Where building.CityID IS NULL
```

Но так в список будет попадать страна город в которой не имеет домов, то есть если в стране 3 города и в 2 из них нет домов то у меня в списке будет указана эта страна дважды, DISTINCT тоже не поможет так как в списке будет страна в которой хотя бы один город не имеет домов. 
Буду рад помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого

```
SELECT country.Name FROM Country AS country
INNER JOIN City AS city ON country.CountryID = city.CountryID
LEFT JOIN Building AS building ON city.CityID = building.CityID 
GROUP BY country.id
HAVING sum(if(building.id is null,0,1)) = 0 --просуммируем количество домов в стране
```

Останутся только названия стран, в которых не будет ни одного города вообще.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Заработало!!!

Comment: Достаточно `HAVING COUNT(building.id) = 0`.

Comment: Count в такой конструкции даст ровно столько же сколько и записей будет. Потому что count считает количество строк не взирая на то что там NULL будет